# The batch function passed to the ".run" method didn't return a promise

Tags: javascript, office-js

Although I do realize what the error means and why it happens, I think I have a use case that goes outside the expected. I am using `Word.run()` inside another promise, like so:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  window.Word.run(context => {
    // do stuff with context
    resolve(someData);
  });
});
```

So, if I understood it correctly, this resolves my promise, but leaves the `.run` method hanging since there's no `return context.sync()` at the end? Or did I get it wrong? If I'm right, how can I rewrite the example above to keep `.run` working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your promise to resolve after the context syncs...

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  window.Word.run(context => {
    // do stuff with context
    return context.sync().then(function() {
      resolve(someData); // promise will resolve after sync resolves
    });
  });
});
```

If you don't need to resolve **after** but just want to sync the context at some point in the future, you can actually do this and it won't wait for the sync:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  window.Word.run(context => {
    // do stuff with context
    resolve(someData); // this will resolve the promise
    return context.sync(); // this will actually still happen since the function never returns
  });
});
```